# centos7 what is the best value of audit.rules

Tags: linux, memory, logging, auditd

I am now suffered with `audit : backlog limit exceeded`.

I found some articles with similar situation and they said adjust audit log count with `audit.rules`.

Here is my `audit.rules`

```
## This file is automatically generated from /etc/audit/rules.d
-D
-b 320
```

I would like to change that `320` to somewhat higher, but I do not know how to set proper values. (I do not even know this value is concerned with memory or openfiles)

By watching `audit.log`, I assume that it records almost every command working with daemon process. I got 4 docker containers and 1 qemu VM in the machine.

A suggestion or reference will be very appreciated. I would like to set the best value to this `audit`, so want to prevent machine become disabled.
Thanks!

FYI, this is my `memInfo`

```
MemTotal:       65755736 kB
MemFree:        62985572 kB
MemAvailable:   63955852 kB
Buffers:            5136 kB
Cached:          1169252 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          1198532 kB
Inactive:         750240 kB
Active(anon):     775204 kB
Inactive(anon):     8352 kB
Active(file):     423328 kB
Inactive(file):   741888 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:      29200380 kB
SwapFree:       29200380 kB
Dirty:              6708 kB
Writeback:           964 kB
AnonPages:        799520 kB
Mapped:            38752 kB
Shmem:              9140 kB
Slab:             170132 kB
SReclaimable:      60620 kB
SUnreclaim:       109512 kB
KernelStack:        8448 kB
PageTables:        39464 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    62078248 kB
Committed_AS:   17605768 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      497488 kB
VmallocChunk:   34325640552 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    686080 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      139264 kB
DirectMap2M:     4026368 kB
DirectMap1G:    65011712 kB
```